# Screw Sizes for Electrical Connection box lids

Tags: electrical, screws

Am having to install covers to several different types of electrical connections boxes in my house. Some are round, blue ones and some are a grayish tan with corners rounded. None of them have cover screws in them, so I am having to go buy screws to attach  the covers. What type and size of screws are need for each type of connection box?

Comment: Generally the screw you need should come with the cover.  Typically cover screws are 6/32.

Comment: Do your faceplates not come with screws?

Answer (score 1):

Most hardware stores I have been to had a specific electrical screw section in their fastener area. They should basically be labelled as electrical box cover screws, and you can find them in all kinds of versions: long/short, metal/plastic, and different finish colors.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a supply of #6-32, #8-32 and #10-32 (which is a fine thread) in my electrical screw bin.

Code requires a -32 thread *or finer* for grounding screws, because a standard steel junction box has a metal thickness such that -32 will give enough thread engagement to be secure.  -40 would be allowed; -24 would not. By coincidence, [NC (National Coarse)](https://www.newmantools.com/taps/tapsinch.htm) thread sizes are 6-32 and 8-32, and NF (National Fine) is 10-32.  And that is why [this tool](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/tapping-tools/triple-taps-6-32-8-32-10-32) exists.

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to answer but, Could you provide photos, your description almost sounds like wire nuts both made in tan and blue. 
I think you are talking about cutthler hammer panels the gray/tan but there are a large number of different manufactures of the blue ish covers.

load center cover screws are not standard screws. They have a larger head, some have a fine pitch like Siemens ects2 or Square D S106 then almost wood screw look for Eaton LCCSCS. These are closer to #10 size with a large head #2 square drive or flat blade screwdriver and the first 1/8" is not threaded to get the screw in the hole. I know quite a few electrical inspectors and home inspectors that look for the correct screws this is why I provided the part numbers of the main ones I keep spares of.

Comment: I think he's talking about ordinary junction boxes, not loadcenter cabinets...

Comment: I was not sure but the colors I thought load centers that's why I asked for pics.